# Which version of Hibernate-OGM Neo4j dependencies to use?

Tags: hibernate, neo4j, version, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to use Neo4j with Hibernate-OGM. Something is not right with the versions. I either get errors messages like version in the database is expected to be something like `v0.A.1` but it's `v0.A.5` instead or a `NoSuchMethodError` or something similar at deployment because the `hibernate`, `hibernate-ogm` or `neo4j` versions don't match with each other (or with the database).

The only thing that seems to be sure that the Neo4j database version should be 2.1.x, because newer versions don't support JTA.

Example for the exceptions:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.io.pagecache.impl.SingleFilePageSwapperFactory: method <init>()V not found
```

or

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

or

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be some example code or tests that have the correct version combo in the hibernate-ogm repository?

Comment: As I see they focused on JBoss/Wildfly development. I think that's why they don't have any specific settings for hibernate core versions for example. (Or I just can't find them.) I'm stuck with Glasshfish, which uses EclipseLink and not Hibernate, so I have to figure out that part too. (And when that part seems fine then the other parts fall apart.)

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate OGM 4.2.0 Final works with Neo4j 2.1.8: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-ogm/blob/c801f17640d5c687a27ab57e2b2dd0aa0cd89fff/bom/pom.xml#L30

You can find all the versions in the [maven BOM](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-ogm/blob/c801f17640d5c687a27ab57e2b2dd0aa0cd89fff/bom/pom.xml#L22):

- Hibernate ORM 4.3.9.Final
- Neo4j 2.1.8

Note that in the next release Hibernate OGM will use Neo4j 2.2.3 and Hibernate ORM 5.x.

I hope this help.

Comment: With these version numbers I still get the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()` exception when I try to deploy the application in Glassfish. Is there another component in play then which I didn't consider?

Comment: I guess the library you are using on the classpath for the JPA API is not aligned with the 2.1 specification